# Is it possible to know which one triggered Collection's add event: fetch or create call?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-events, backbone.js-collections

I need to tell if model inside `add` event was retrieved with `collection.fetch` or created by `collection.create`. Is it possible?

```
collection.on('add', onModelAdded)
collection.fetch()
collection.create({})

function onModelAdded(model, collection, options) {
   // created or fetched?
}
```

Comment: Have you tried overriding `create` to piggy back something through the `options`?

Comment: @muistooshort nice idea, trying to implement it right now.

Comment: @muistooshort it worked, thanks. Please post an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Thanks for the `apply` -> `call` fix, I always get those two mixed up enough that I actually have [`call` bookmarked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) at MDN as a reminder :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that something like this `create` override would work:

```
create: function(attributes, options) {
    options = options || { };
    options.came_from_create = true;
    return Backbone.Collection.prototype.create.call(this, attributes, options);
}
```

Then you could look for `came_from_create` in your callback:

```
function onModelAdded(model, collection, options) {
    if(options && options.came_from_create) {
        // We started in a create call on the collection.
    }
    else {
        // We came from somewhere else.
    }
}
```

You can usually use the `options` argument to piggy back bits of data around if you're careful not to use any option names that Backbone wants to use.

Answer (score 0):

from [Backbone Docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-isNew)

> **isNew**
>
> Has this model been saved to the server yet? If
>   the model does not yet have an id, it is considered to be new.

Backbone source :

```
isNew: function() {
   return this.id == null;
},
```

When creating model not setting id then it's a new model (model without id considered as new), and therefore `model.isNew()` returns true

```
function onModelAdded(model, collection, options) {
   if(model.isNew()){
       // It's created
   }else{
       // It's fetched!
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot rely on this, because I might have `{wait: true}`.

Comment: Another idea is to set a flag (by overriding backbone create method) and after model save complete unset the flag,

`create: function(model,collection){
...
   if (options.wait) {
      model.createdNew = true;
      model.once('sync',function(){delete this.createdNew};
   }
...
}`

Can't test this solution, but hope it works!